# What is the life time of iteration variable in for-each loop

Tags: java

What is the life time of iteration variable in for-each loop? final variable can't be used as iteration variable in for loop but for-each loop can. What's the reason for that?

```
class Example1{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] marks={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
    for(final int a : marks){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

}

```
class Example2{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] marks={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
    for(final int a=0;a<marks.length;a++){ //compile error
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

}

```
class Example3{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] marks={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
    int a=0; // final int a is illegal
    for(;a<marks.length;a++){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Get this idea of _lifetime_ out of your head. What you probably mean is _scope_ and scope is a compile time concept defining where a name (or identifier) can be used in the source code of a program. For your case, the name `a` can only be used inside the body of the enhanced `for` statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "lifetime"? Do you mean "scope"? If so, why don't you just try to use `a` outside of the loop, and see by yourself?

Comment: Really, this should be two questions, since it's asking about scope and the final modifier, which are two very different concepts. I've attempted to answer the `final` part, since others have addressed the scope question.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of any variable is with the `{` `}` brackets it is defined in.  However in this case it is limit to the for-each itself.

```
// you cannot use `a` here
for(final int a : marks){
    System.out.println(a);
}
// you cannot use `a` here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it, but it seems that the definition of scope's variable is to be created (allocated), alive (used) and killed (desallocated). This happens into function brackets and parameters' life.
From this example:

```
for (final int a : marks) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Here, you have `a` in `()` which is allocated in memory AND also `a` in `{}`. Thus, you have two allocations, two creations. At the end of brackets - end of using function -, the two variables are desallocated and destroyed from memory.

Therefore, using `a` outside `{}` is impossible because it's destroyed. To use this value (not sure that will be revelant with `for loop`, but it's to understand the idea), you have to create outside the `{}` of the function as follows:

```
int a = 0; // variable inside class

foo() {
    a = 3; // changed from foo function
}

bar() {
    System.out.println(a); // used from bar function
}
```

From this above example, you see that `a` can be used outside `foo()` function, because its allocation is outside it (*outside { ... }*).

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two things here: *scope*, which others have explained, and the *final* modifier. You can use `final` in cases like this:

```
for(final int a : marks) {
    ...
}
```

because `a` is never changed once it goes into scope. It changes for each iteration of the loop, but essentially it is a new variable with each iteration.

However, you **cannot** use `final` here:

```
for(final int a=0; a<marks.length; a++) { // compile error
    ...
}
```

because the loop variable is changing with every iteration, due to the third expression in the `for` statement, which in your case is `a++` (in other words, add one to `a`, which causes a compile error if `a` is declared `final`).